# Coverage Criteria, What are independent conditions exactly?

Tags: testing, conditional-statements, specifications, verification

When speaking of coverage criteria such as MCDC (Modified Condition/Decision Criteria)...

It is stated that "Every point of entry and exit in the program has been invoked at least once, every condition in a decision in the program has taken all possible outcomes at least once, **and each condition has been shown to affect that decision outcome independently**. **A condition is shown to affect a decision's outcome independently by varying just that condition while holding fixed all other possible conditions.** [...]"
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage

This description is rather vague of what constitutes an independent criteria... So, what are they? Examples are helpful in any language (C-family/python/haskell preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia definition is an informal statement, a more precise definition of MDCD is:

For each condition `c`, in each decision `d`, there is a test such that:

- There is a test such that `c == true`
- There is a test such that `c == false`
- If the outcome of `d` when `c == true` is `x`, then the result of d when `c == false` must be `!x`.
- All other conditions in `d` evaluate identically in both test cases.

If it is possible to create test set which meet these criteria, then this shows that each condition is not redundant: each condition at least influences the control of the program in some situation (as there is a test case that demonstrates this). This is what is meant by "independently influences the outcome".